# Find function automatical highlight different column permanantly

Tags: google-sheets, automation, find, conditional-formatting

I am trying to simulate a Good Receipt process with Google sheets.
I have tried multiply options with conditional formatting, but i actually think, this is not possible.

What i am trying to achieve:
I scan a barcode in the "Find" box on top of my sheet.
The sheet automatically marks rows who have that number.

And now the tricky part.
I now need in row A - the field automatically marked as "Recieved", for all rows, where that Barcode number was found.

here you can find the sheet which I am working with.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1txDg_azE6ew87ljDo6IwkmSWEehGHWo6yTlMRjZCQVU/edit?usp=sharing

Column: PkgID (C) & BOL (R) are mostly the numbers I have to scan

Is there any way to integrate this with the find option?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mark the field as received, you can use this script. You will get a new menu. Then scan the number within the inputbox ...

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⇩ M E N U ⇩')
    .addItem(' Find a number ...', 'displayPrompt')
    .addToUi();
}

function displayPrompt() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt("Please scan the number");
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  if (button === ui.Button.OK) {
    check(result.getResponseText());
  } 
}

function check(searchText) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Original');
  var rangeList = sheet
    .getRange('C2:C')
    .createTextFinder(searchText)
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .findAll()
    .map((r) => r.offset(0, -2).setValue('Received'));
  var rangeList = sheet
    .getRange('R2:R')
    .createTextFinder(searchText)
    .matchEntireCell(true)
    .findAll()
    .map((r) => r.offset(0, -17).setValue('Received'));
}
```

to expand to all columns and all tabs

```
function check(searchText) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().forEach(function (sheet) {
    sheet
      .getRange('B2:AT')
      .createTextFinder(searchText)
      .matchEntireCell(true)
      .findAll()
      .map((r) => sheet.getRange(r.getRow(), 1).setValue('Received'));
  })
}
```

to expand to all columns, all tabs excluding some ones and activate the last row of each tab

```
function checkAndActivate(searchText) {
  const excl = ['Sheet1','Sheet2'];//excluded sheets
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().filter(sh => !~excl.indexOf(sh.getName())).forEach(function (sheet){
    sheet.activate()
    var rows = sheet
      .getRange('B2:AT')
      .createTextFinder(searchText)
      .matchEntireCell(true)
      .findAll()
      .map((r) =>
        r.getRow()
      );

    try {
      rows.forEach(function(row) {
        sheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue('Received')
      })
      sheet.getRange(rows[rows.length - 1],1).activate()
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    } catch (e) { }

  })
}
```

Comment: Hello
I am trying to do that. But it doesn't work. It also tells me, I have to authorize it but I dont know how. "A script attached to this document needs your permission to run." 
when I go to the script app, I dont have any option to approve it

Comment: open the script editor, run onOpen, google will ask you for permission, answer until the end, you will get an error but the script will be functional, and let me know if it's ok!

Comment: ah sorry, yes got it.. works perfekt! Genious!!
I have now adition question:
1. Could there also be edit that if column C doesnt work. see column R? or maybe dont even assign a column at all, and cross check the whole sheet?
2. Can this also work on multiply tabs in one spreadsheet?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

just an idea...

instead of simple Find box use <kbd>**CTRL + H**</kbd> where you search it wrapped in parenthesis like:

[image]

and you will replace it with:

```
$1
```

take extra notice of the invisible character after `$1`

you can get it by running this formula and copy it from the middle (after you enter the cell)

```
={"", "﹀﹀﹀﹀﹀﹀﹀", ""; 
 ">>>>>>>>>>>>", CHAR(32), "<<<<<<<<<<<<";
 "", "︿︿︿︿︿︿︿", ""}
```

[image]

next, you can go to conditional formatting and use:

```
=REGEXMATCH(C1, CHAR(32))
```

[image]

Comment: hi, thank you for that. I think its to complex and not fast enough.